# Preventing of maven update in Spring Roo replaces all the file in AspectJ files ?

Tags: maven, spring-roo

When maven update in spring roo it replace all the file in AspectJ files.
How to prevent from it?

I want to write code in controller file and do not want to replace my code after maven update.

Answer (score 0):

Are you modifying XyzController.java oder XyzController_Roo_Controller.aj? Updating the .aj files will always cause you grief with Roo. Normally, you'd copy the methods you want to update into XyzController.java and change them there. After the next refresh, Roo won't create the method in the .aj file any more are your changes won't disappear.